# How writes will be distributed across different shards when I use only mongoimport for write activity...?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongoimport

we are going to use mongo db for an alert monitoring application.

We thought first to write the data to files and then to write it onto mongodb using mongoimport utility. Each file will have 1Mill records on an average.

Here my question is "shall we sharding here...?"

I guess mongoimport is not aware of sharding. 
How does sharding works when writes are happening by mongoimport...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your collection exists and is sharded and you run mongoimport against a mongos router, then it will respect sharding rules (writes will be distributed according to chunk location).

#### Footnote

If you have a mongodb cluster, you have to have `mongos` daemon(s) in there. `mongos` reads your cluster configuration from config servers and knows where to route requests from your app. In a cluster configuration you should never talk to `mongod` servers directly, only via `mongos`. Read more about cluster configuration [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction).

Comment: How to run mongoimprt against a mongos router....?                                                         I think u r telling to run mongoimport with port value as that of mongos.                                                             Please explain otherwise. sorry if it sense pretty silly.

Comment: common mongoimport command is mongoimport -d dbname -c collecions_name importfile_name                                                           how do we tell this command to run against mongos...? do u mean we need to give the port as the mongos port...?